# How to get specific list items in Document Library subfolder?

Tags: development, document-library

I'm attempting to retrieve items from a subfolder in a document library. I must get these items where value is 'Like'. How can I do this via C# using the SP object model or by CAML query?

this is what I have so far:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySite/Shared Documents/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //get sub folder url
                string SubFolderUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/shared documents/SubFolderName";

                //able to get the subfolder at this point
                SPFolder SubFolder = web.GetFolder(SubFolderUrl);

                //Now what could I do from here to get the items in the subfolder?
                //use SPQuery object against the folder?
            }
         }
```

any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: When you say "where value is 'Like'," do you mean that you want to get files with names similar to a given string, or do you just want to get a list item with a specific name?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. When I say 'Like' I mean it in the same terms as a sql query 'Like'. ie Select * from tbl where attribute Like <value>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can indeed use SPQuery for this.  Here's some code that does what you want to do:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySite/Shared Documents/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        //get sub folder url
        string SubFolderUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/shared documents/SubFolderName";

        //able to get the subfolder at this point
        SPFolder SubFolder = web.GetFolder(SubFolderUrl);

        //create an SPQuery that gets us what we want
        string fileName = "FileName";
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value></Contains></Where>";
        query.Folder = SubFolder;  // This should restrict the query to the subfolder

        //run the SPQuery against the SPList
        SPDocumentLibrary list = SubFolder.DocumentLibrary;
        SPListItemCollection files = list.GetItems(query);
    }
}
```

This code takes whatever the search query should be in the `string` **fileName** and returns all files with **fileName** in its Title.

The `SPListItemCollection` **files** should contain the files you're looking for.  Please note that I haven't tested this code nor have I done error checking (you should probably check if the `SPDocumentLibrary` **list** is not null at least).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get a bevy of errors when trying to save to `SPListItemCollection` object. I'm currently trying to see if I can save to `SPFileCollection` instead, but have not had any luck so far.

Comment: Well, what's the first error message?  Is **list** not null?  If it isn't, maybe something's wrong with the CAML query -- if this is the case, see what happens when `query.Query` is not set.  This should return all items in the folder.

Comment: list is **not** null. I am able to step over `SPListItemCollection files = ...` without any hitch. When I rexamined the object however, all properties in `files` are throwing exceptions.

Comment: Please excuse the "Is your computer plugged in" question, but you changed the `string fileName = "FileName";` into something that matches a `SPListItem` title in that subfolder, right?

Comment: lol well I opted to put the value directly in the query and save myself the typing of `string fileName...`. But to answer your question, yes I did reference the title of an item in the subfolder.

Comment: What does `files.Count` give you?  Have you tried to do a quick iteration over the items in there?

Comment: Inspecting the `SPListItemCollection files` object, files.count reads "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

Comment: The CAML query is incorrect.  First, we both know that `Title` is the correct internal name, so that's okay.  I have a feeling that the `<Value Type="Note">...</Value>` is incorrect.  Try changing that to `<Value Type="Text">..</Value>`.

Comment: Jeff's correct that "Note" isn't a proper value type and `Text` should've been used.  But I also had the same error, once.  Found out it was happening because I had the right query, but I was using the main site's SPSite and SPWeb, which didn't have the list I was querying.  I needed to open a new SPWeb to the document's site, "/Docs/", first.